# Lua string length (cyrillic in utf8)

Tags: string, utf-8, lua, symbols, cyrillic

How to get the REAL length of the string with cyrillic symbols in lua?

If i'm using string.len("HELLO.") - I will get 6

But with string.len("ПРИВЕТ") - I will get 12(Same with "#" operator)

So the number of symbols didn't changed, but we got different numbers...
It's because cyrillic symbols has two bytes, when english letters, numbers and etc has 1.
I want to know how to get the right and real length of string(Get 6 in both samples).
Everyone who can help?

Comment: To be clear, a Lua string is a counted sequence of bytes. _Some_ of functions in the string library operate on the assumption that those bytes are text when viewed with respect to the current locale. (Locale includes a character encoding.) Specifically, `len` and `#` return the number of bytes in the string, regardless of those bytes being encoded text.

Comment: `str_len = #('ПРЕВЕД!'):gsub('[\128-\191]', '')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string.len` and `#` count *bytes*, not *chars*.

In Lua 5.3+, use `utf8.len`.